# How in Eclipse to poll CVS for files I'm editing

Tags: eclipse, edit, cvs

Is there a way for Eclipse within a Java project to display what files the CVS thinks I'm editing?  I'm trying to "Unedit" files I could have sworn I "Unedited" months ago (as I no longer intend to make changes to those files, and I have no local changes to those files).

Another way to think of this is: if I marked files for editing on my PC, and installed Eclipse with the same CVS user on a different PC, could that other PC see which files I marked for editing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you just need to see the changed files?

If so, just right click on the project folder in the `Project Explorer` and select `Team -> Synchronize with Repository`. That should bring you to a view that shows the changes.

Comment: Note: you don't have to select the project in Project Explorer, you can select it in any view where the projects are listed. You can also select other "entities" besides projects, like folders, individual or sets of files, etc.

Comment: It's a little more than that, I also need to see files I haven't changed which the CVS thinks I have checked out for editing (but Eclipse thinks I don't have checked out for editing).

Comment: I really don't know what you mean by "checked out for editing" or "marked files for editing". I think you need to read a CVS tutorial.

Comment: The way I understand it, it's possible to configure Eclipse such that checked out files are read-only and edit notifications are sent to the CVS server before you start editing a file; and when the CVS server receives such a notification, Eclipse copies the read-only file into a local directory and marks the file you want to start editing in read/write mode.  However, there's the possibility (and in my case, this is what happened) that the CVS server is corrupted and notifies other developers that I'm editing files which I never touched.

Comment: I think you might be talking about reserved checkouts or locking, but I'm not sure. It's also possible that you've worked with a modified version of CVS with extra hooks before. What you describe certainly isn't the default model: http://ximbiot.com/cvs/manual/cvs-1.11.23/cvs_10.html#SEC82